# Is there a minimal Heap Size

Tags: c++, c

I am on an 32bit old machine. And want to learn how things are going on in deep. The Heap implementation on this system is really old I think it uses an older malloc algorithm. 
Now my question is.
This is my programm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fp {

 int (*fpd)();
};

int main() 
{
    int *ptr;
    malloc(sizeof(struct fp));
    printf("Size:%d\n",sizeof(struct fp));
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the programm the output is 4.
So the heap chunk size should be 4byte header + 4byte size + 4byte(sizeof struct)
so the heap should be 12 bytes equals to 0xc

But if I look at the heap in gdb it tells me the size of a chunk of 0x10
equals to 16bytes but from where are the other 4 bytes. That's confusing me!

Or is it possible that a minimum chunksize exists which is 0x10?

Comment: `malloc` implementation details are not regulated by any standard. Open the source code of it and look there if it really matters to you.

Comment: It is *entirely* possible that `malloc()` obtains memory in 16-byte (or larger) chunks.  In that case, it could well be that there is more overhead than you suppose, or simply that more space was obtained from the OS than you requested.  Not that any such extra space would be safe to use -- `malloc()` could potentially use it to satisfy some future request without obtaining any additional memory from the OS.

Comment: how do I get my malloc source code? @Eugene Sh.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? But.. come on. Why do you need to know? I've survived over a decade of C experience without this knowledge.

Comment: All the source code to GCC is here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/ Not sure what you're using.

Comment: It is entirely possible (and fairly routine) that heap allocations are rounded up to (for example) the next power of 2 in size.

Comment: where are these assumptions about malloc using a header or size?  what system are you on, why wouldnt they use an mmu table, why have a separate set of parameters, etc? why isnt the minimum size 4096 or 8192?  There is value in looking into how it works.  So go do that...If you dont know how/where then you are not ready to go do that, work on how do libraries work and how do system calls work.

Comment: Since you did not mention what system you are working on, it may be interesting to note that some systems do not allocate a heap *at all*. I am currently working on an embedded project where a decision was made that all allocations will be static, and such we do not use a heap, and by not allocating space for one, we save precious system memory.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a minimal Heap Size (?)

It sounds like OP wants to know the minimum allocation size, not the total size of the "heap".

---

All `*alloc()`, when successful returning non-`NULL` (** see below), "yield a pointer to an object disjoint from any other object."  C11 §7.22.3 1.

All such pointers meet the *fundamental alignment* requirement.

The *fundamental alignment* is "is equal to `_Alignof(max_align_t)`"  §6.2.8 2

So the `alignof(max_align_t)`, example 4, is a **lower bound minimum  for a "heap" allocation** and all allocation will also be a multiple of 4.

Typically allocations incur a overhead per allocation, sometimes just 1 `sizeof(max_align_t)`.  In our sample system, the lower bound would then be 8.

> is it possible that a minimum chunksize exists which is 0x10?

Yes. For performance reasons or to minimize fragmentation, allocations may further limit the minimum size to some lower bound like 16. [@ John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356079/is-there-a-minimal-heap-size#comment73775569_43356079)

The absolute lower allocation size varies from platform to platform.  Is is not specified by C other than it meets the constraints of the *fundamental alignment*.

---

** Detail:  `malloc(0)` can successfully return `NULL`, so one could say in that pathological case, the min allocation size is 0.

Comment: 6.2.8 2 does not define fundamental alignment to be equal to `_Alignof(max_align_t)`. It mentions that the maximum alignment supported by the implementation is equal to that. **A** (not **the**) fundamental alignment is less than or equal to that. Fundamental alignment is per-type; `char`, `int`, and `double` each have their own fundamental alignment. So I am not sure 7.22.3 1 is requiring `malloc` *et al* to return only pointers with the maximum required. If you allocate just enough space for an `int` but not a `double`, I am not sure it is required to return something aligned for a `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree that `malloc(sizeof(int))` need not be as restrictive as `malloc(sizeof(int))`, yet  "The pointer returned ... is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to **any** type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement ..." (7.22.3 1) does not provide that. The pointer return is aligned for all objects.

Comment: Sure, but the fact that you can assign to any type of object does not mean it necessarily has the alignment that type requires. (C has a rule that converting pointers between object types works if the alignment requirements are satisfied. But that does not mean an implementation cannot allow this even if requirements are not satisfied. So `malloc(4)` could return a 4-mod-8 pointer, and the implementation can allow you to assign it to a pointer to an 8-byte `double` because it has a simple addressing scheme that is fine with assigning any pointer to any other pointer. Obviously, you cannot…

Comment: … store a `double` in the space being pointed to, but you’ve satisfied the standard’s requirement that it be possible to assign the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Allocator can have any minimum chunk size. It is implementation details. You don't have to care about this until you want to change the allocator for your program.